# Specified table does not exist

Tags: c#, sql, xml, windows-phone-7, hyperlink

I'm searching for an answer to this question. I don't know where is the problem. Visual Studio does not see any problem or error, but when I run program and try to add something to database, application crashes and VS tell me that my table does not exist. That event is for adding something.

This is my code:

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        using (WpisyDataContext BazaDanych = new WpisyDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            if (!BazaDanych.DatabaseExists())
            {
                BazaDanych.CreateDatabase();
                MessageBox.Show("BazaDanych Database Created Successfully!!!");
            }

            Wpis newWpis = new Wpis
            {

                RecordID = index_box.Text,
                NameRec = name_box.Text.ToString(),
                BeneficiaryRec = beneficiary_box.Text.ToString(),
                PriceRec = price_box.Text.ToString(),
                DeadlineRec = deadline_box.Text.ToString(),
                DescriptionRec = description_box.Text.ToString()
            };

            BazaDanych.Wpisy.InsertOnSubmit(newWpis);
            BazaDanych.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Recoed Added Successfully!!!");
            if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            } 
        }  
    }
}
```

This is the table code (`Wpis.cs`):

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
namespace ********
{
    [Table]
    public class Wpis
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public string RecordID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
        public string NameRec
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
        public string BeneficiaryRec
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
        public string PriceRec
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
        public string DeadlineRec
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
        public string DescriptionRec
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the data context (`WpisyDataContext.cs`):

```
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace *************
{
    public class WpisyDataContext : DataContext
    {
        public WpisyDataContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
        public Table<Wpis> Wpisy
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Wpis>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is connection string:

```
public static string strConnectionString = @"Data Source=isostore:/DevDB.sdf";
```

Please guys, I don't have any more patience. Thanks.

Comment: Put a try/catch around your using, then show the exception or log it. There's no way of telling what's in your DB so the table may actually be missing

Comment: Do your `CreateDatabase` method creates a table names `wpis`? You have not specified any Name attribute to the mapping code, so your table should be named as your class (Wpis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `CreateDatabase()`, please check whether .Net has created the database table as your Entity. Because EntityFramework create table with Plural name and Entity is created with singular name.

Check whether the created table name is as expected.

Comment: @Steve: I fetched my database and table "Wpis" really exist. For the rest who dont know polish language( :P ), word 'Wpis' means 'Record' and 'Wpisy' means 'Records'. Have you got another idea ?